# Trying to modify the hardware back button behaviour in some pages in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Lets say I have 5 pages in my Ionic app: A, B, C, D, and E.

I'm trying to change the hardware back button behaviour in A and B, but in the rest I want it to behave like it would normally do.

When I open the app the hardware back button behave like always, then when I visit A or B it successfully change its behaviour with custom method I want to use with the following code:

```
  constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
      this.goBack()
    });
  }

  goBack() {
    // code for my custom back method
  }
```

Until this moment everything is working fine... **The problem I'm facing is that the moment I visit any other page, different than A or B, the hardware back button seems to stop working for ever** (until I restart the app), even if I come back to A or B it just doesn't do anything, it's like it simply crash.

**So what can I do to make the hardware back button behave normally in C, D and E, but in A and B use my custom back method?**

Comment: I don't know, but I supouse you can add Location as service in your app, and if is C,D and E use location.back() https://angular.io/api/common/Location#back

Comment: @Eliseo I would like another solution, I have more than 100 pages...

Comment: Please take a look at the answer linked above. I think that'd solve your issue, but please let me know if it doesn't so I can reopen your question. Thanks :)

Comment: @OiciTrap, I don't have experience with ionic, but I supouse you only need to put in your main-app.ts. if is A or B, call a Subject in a service (yes A and B must be subscribe to the subject)